# Ubuntu 14.04.02/14.10 stuck on "Prepare to install"

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, 14.10

I have try installing both `14.04.02` and `14.10` but the installation stuck here:

[image]

when I hit on the `Continue` button. I have try all variants (checked/unchecked `Downloading updates while installing` and `Install this third-party software`).

I have never had such issues with previous `Ubuntu` versions.

Comment: It takes more than usual (like 2-3 minutes) on my system, how long did you wait?

Comment: @th0th About 10 minutes... the last time 25 minutes ... then I have restarted.

Comment: Leave it overnight it my suggestion. It takes a long time on some of my hardware!

Comment: @Tim Sure, I will try and come back with the results tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the @Tim suggested in his comment, leaving the option through the night fix the issue. I cannot tell exactly how many time it cost to move to the next installation screen, but simple wait if you have the same issue.